# React-Native how to update Flat List updating item dynamically?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wanted to update the List based on the 'address' and attach more 
codes to it.

I wanted to update the existing Flistlist that is already populated with new incoming data

**ANSWER**: I got it now. I need to update my list using state change  and FlatList Renders my list as new list everytime I update it, therefore data will remain updated everytime.

like:

> if(address=='xyz')
>   { code= code+newCode; }

```js
<FlatList

    extraData={this.state}
    data={this.state.TESTDATA}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.Code.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => console.log('pressed TouchableOpacity')}
            style={{
                height: 75,
            }}
        >
            <View style={styles.listItem}>

                <Text style={styles.baseText}>
                    Stop Address: {item.Address}{'\n'}
                    codes:    {item.Code}
            </Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )}
  />
```

Comment: try like `if(condition) && <View>Your Content</View>`

Comment: you're trying to change the things that you display in the list right?

Comment: yes I wanted to update the existing list that is already populated

Comment: I don't understand your question. To update your list, you only have to update `this.state.data` by adding the new incoming data.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now. I need to update my list and FlatList Renders my list as new list everytime I update it